# Oozie: run at some time or at some frequency, whichever comes first

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

the benefits of coordinating by an absolute time is that (insofar as the jobs take a consistent amount of time) the output will be ready for others at some time (e.g. update a dashboard during the night for people to see in the morning).

the benefits of coordinating by a relative frequency is that, if oozie (or it's server) are down, no jobs are skipped (e.g. a daily job might run 2 hours late, but not 22 hours late).

how can i do something like:

```
start="2009-01-01T21:00Z"
frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
run-if-skipped="true"
```

i.e. when all's well, jobs run daily at 9pm. if something happens to oozie (e.g. the server is rolled) between 8pm and 10pm, once oozie comes back up at 10pm, the job should run at 10pm, and then tomorrow at 9pm as normal.

https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I fully understand the question.

If server is down, and you re-start you coordinator, so it will start from the coordinator start time.

Also you can make you job run every hour, check if the output folder exist - that stop . for that use [Decision Control Node](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node)

Comment: i would like the job to immediately run when oozie starts, *if* it hasn't run for at least 24h. otherwise, the job should wait to run at its specific time, even if oozie is restarted.